# This backup cannot be restored using WITH STANDBY because a database upgrade is needed. Reissue the RESTORE without WITH STANDBY

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, restore, log-shipping, standby

I am creating log shipping for two databases, db1 and db2.

It will be from SQL Server 2008 R2 to a newer version, SQL Server 2012.

On SQL Server 2008R2, they are both `dbi_version` = 661:

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604);  
GO 
DBCC PAGE (db1, 1, 9, 3); 
GO 
DBCC TRACEOFF (3604);
```

I restore them in standby mode:

```
RESTORE DATABASE db1 FROM DISK = 'Q:\db1.bak' WITH STANDBY = N'R:\SQLLog\db1.undo'
```

One of them restores ok, with upgrade, and another one is giving me error:

> This backup cannot be restored using WITH STANDBY because a database upgrade is needed. Reissue the RESTORE without WITH STANDBY.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`WITH STANDBY` is only supported when both SQL Servers are the same version.

You can only use `WITH NORECOVERY`

An alternative if you need read access to the destination databases, is to use replication.