# How to do log shipping when SQL server versions are different?

Tags: log-shipping

I have SQL2014 version database on my Windows12 server. I want to add the databases in SQL2014 to SQL 2022 on my Windows2016 server using the Log Shipping method. Since the versions are different, I think I had to select No Recovery Mode instead of Standby Mode in the "Restore Transaction Log" section. I also selected No recovery mode, but I could not access the database added from SQL 2022 on my Windows 2016 server. How can I access SQL2014 databases from SQL2022 database with Log Shipping?

Comment: Put it in `STANDBY` instead of `NORECOVERY`

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55072/this-backup-cannot-be-restored-using-with-standby-because-a-database-upgrade-is

In this link it says that WITH NORECOVERY should be used. Because my SQL versions are not the same.  @Charlieface

Comment: Well there is your answer, it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are log shipping to a newer version of SQL Server there would be no way to read from the databases.  The STANDBY option won't work.  You would need to restore with RECOVERY to read from them - which will prevent any further log restores.

Usually log shipping is done to a newer version of SQL Server as part of a migration process to minimize downtime.  If you are doing it for HA/DR purposes, log shipping to a newer version is not recommended as you wouldn't be able to go back to the old primary *(Not without upgrading it to the newer version)*.  If you just want a copy to read from - keeping the versions the same is mandatory.